# "AVFoundationErrorDomain" - code: 1844

Tags: swift, dns, avcapture

i'm trying to write a simple code to capture video using Swift

=====Code=========

```
override init() {
    var err:NSErrorPointer = NSErrorPointer();
    camDev = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo);
    camSession =  AVCaptureSession();
    camDevInp = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(camDev,error: err) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    videoOp = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput();

    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentDir = paths[0] as String;
    var fileNamePostfix = 0
    do {
        filePath = "\(documentDir)/test\(fileNamePostfix++).mp4"
    } while (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath))
    fileUrlPath = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)!;
    //fileUrlPath = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("\(NSTemporaryDirectory())/testVideo.mov")!

    camSession.beginConfiguration();
    if(camSession.canAddInput(camDevInp)){
        camSession.addInput(camDevInp);
    }
    if(camSession.canAddOutput(videoOp)){
        camSession.addOutput(videoOp);
    }

    camSession.commitConfiguration();

}

func startCapture() -> Void
{
    camSession.startRunning();
    videoOp.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(self.fileUrlPath, recordingDelegate: self);
}
```

==================

the Delegate function func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) is called with this error:
Some    NSError domain: "AVFoundationErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709539811  0x0000608000051100

Comment: you could always call "`error!.localizedDescription`" and find out *exactly* what that error is all about.

Comment: it gives me: Cannot Record

Comment: @msalam: Did you ever figure this out? I get the same "Cannot Record" message when I try to use `AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice()`.